# Deshabilitar teclado virtual nativo de Android en mi app

Tags: java, android, webview, android-softkeyboard, webview-android

Tengo una app que solo contiene un webview (y NO un EditText). En la web que utilizo para la webview, tengo mi propio teclado maquetado por mi, por lo que no quiero que aparezca el teclado nativo del celular/tablet cuando cliqueo un textarea o input. ¿Hay alguna manera de deshabitar el teclado virtual POR COMPLETO en mi app?

Comment: Me parece que esta pregunta no es un duplicado Criss esta preguntando sobre un WebView y no sobre un EditText o TextView que en realidad diferente el control del teclado virtual.

Comment: @Criss prueba lo que comento en mi respuesta y comentame que resultado tienes!.

Comment: No es duplicado porque NO funciona nada de lo que está en ese link

Comment: Que mal que cerraron esta pregunta en realidad, aunque parece  no tiene nada de similar a la pregunta que relacionan =(

Answer (score 1):

Un método para deshabilitar el teclado virtual que es abierto mediante el WebView es primeramente agregar las siguientes propiedades en el WebView:

```
android:focusable="false" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Y en el layout padre que contendrá el WebView

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Este método en realidad lo que hace es desactivar el enfoque en el WebView para evitar iniciar el teclado virtual.

Comment: Hola Elenasys! Ya lo he probado eso y funciona. Sin embargo, me saca el focus cualquier input/textarea que toque en el webview. Y yo necesito que sigan activos, mas solamente que no se abra el softkey nunca en toda la app.

Comment: Hola Criss entiendo lo que dices, el abrir el teclado al enfocar algun elemento que requiere el teclado se debe abrir naturalmente. Si se deshabilitan todos no mostraría el teclado, nunca he requerido de este requerimiento pero sería interesante saber podrían estar activos los demás elementos.

Comment: Hay alguna forma de hacer un "prevent default" del keyboard cuando se hace focus en un input del webview?